# Maven creating different md5 for local jar as compared to one published in remote repository

Tags: maven, md5, nexus

I am using maven-release-plugin v 2.5.2

When I do :

```
mvn clean package
```

I get a jar with a md5 that is different from the jar which gets pushed to my remote repo on doing:

```
mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: If you call Maven twice there are some timestamps in those JAR which could cause the different see [Maven Descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/)...Usually you should only call `mvn release:prepare release:perform` and the artifacts will be built and deployed to remote repository.

Comment: @khmarbaise - After `mvn release:prepare release:perform` I run `mvn clean package` to generate the folder to be deployed to production.